# WPF 2 Windows and 1 Sub

Tags: wpf, vb.net, class

i got a question about my WPF Application. I have a Mainpage and i have some windows which i open to manipulate data and save it back to a database. Everything is working fine, but...when ever the window closes i want to refresh the page, i have a sub which does the refresh, but i can't say the window: do the refresh on the main page. and i cant say the main window: wait until the window is closed and do the refresh.

My page is the Class "Main" and the Window is the Class "SomeWindow".
I start it like this:

```
Dim s As new SomeWindow(somevariable)
s.Show()
```

Does anyone understand my problem? Do i need to do a Partial Class or something like this?
Need help guys!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hook up an event handler for the Window.Closed event after you instantiate your SomeWindow. The handler will run when your SomeWindow closes and you can do whatever you need to do in your main window.

Comment: Good idea, but how to do? :-). can u give me some hints?

Comment: I don't do VB, so I'm not 100% sure of the syntax for vb. You should be able to look it up.